# Test for comparative deviation from a random distribution between two clusterings

Tags: clustering, biostatistics

I have a question related to clustering comparison and biostatistics.

I performed 2 clusterings (let's call them A and B) on a large gene set, so for each gene I have 2 cluster attributions. each clustering contains 10 clusters.

I have a specific subset of genes in which I am interested in this gene set.
My goal is to test if, for this subset of genes, one of these clusterings is significantly more unbalanced than the other (a statistic that would describe well what I want to measure- would be the X2 statistic, a deviation from the expected number of genes across clusters).

I cannot just run a chi2 test between these two clusterings, as cluster 1 in A is not an equivalent category to cluster 1 in B. Also, it wouldn't really answer my question since my goal is to compare how much they deviate from a chi-squared distribution drawn from the complete distribution of the genes in the clustering. A starting possibility would be to try to infer category equivalence between these clusterings, but I wouldn't be satisfied with that as a lot of these choices would be very arbitrary.
EDIT : here is a little scheme of what I am trying to do, to clarify all this a bit

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: You have done 2 separate clustering types, A and B. How many clusters were identified in each of the A and B models? Also, what do you mean by "skewed"? Is that the [technical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) in statistics, or just that your subset of genes co-exist in the same clusters under both the A and B methods? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: I've edited my question, don't hesitate if you need more info

Comment: What was the role of "random sampling in the previous distribution of the genes in the clustering" and how did you do it. And why did you decide to use a single random sampling as a benchmark to compate both distributions against?

Comment: Do you primarily want to have a _coefficient measuring_ the degree of unbalancedness of categories in a categorical distribution? Or maybe you prefer to _compare directly_ two cluster partitions (i.e., ask do those genes - all of them or a subset of them - cluster similarly or differently in the two cluster solutions obtained)?

Comment: edited ! In case it's not completely clear, I want a bit of a mix between your two possibilities : a comparison of the unbancedness of my two categorical distributions

Comment: As for a coefficient of inbalancedness, or non-flatness of a profile of k nonnegative values (such as frequencies), I could imagine of a diversity measure like (max-mean)/(max-min) or of a contrastity measure like (Sum|x-mean|/k)/(max-min). Where x is the value; min, max and mean are the descriptive summaries of the k values. These are simple coefs that come to mind.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll try those indexes out. Keeping the question open in case anyone has other inputs